# How to use AWK to calculate interleaved fields?

Tags: awk, gawk

How can I use `AWK` to calculate some fields on different rows with the pattern like below?

```
(column x, row m) + (column y, row (m+n))
```

Here's a data file to calculate for example,

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
..
```

=>

```
1+4
3+6
5+8
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for the one-behind case,

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print saved + $2 } { saved = $1 }' filename
```

The general case can be solved by

```
awk -v n="$offset" '{ saved[NR] = $1 } NR > n { print saved[NR - n] + $2 }' filename
```

where `$offset` is the number of lines between a set of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1+a} {a=$2}' file
5
9
13
```